# Print all rows including rows hidden by pagination

Tags: javascript, tabulator

The documentation shows by adding `printVisibleRows:false` the `table.print(false,true)` function will print all rows. My table only prints the 20 rows that are visible due to pagination. I would like to print all rows. Is that possible?

```js
//define setup options
var tabData = [{
    invalidOptionWarnings: false,
    layout: fitDatafill,                                    
    printAsHtml:true,                           
    printVisibleRows:false,                                 
    printCopyStyle:true, //copy Tabulator styling to HTML table     
    printHeader:"<h1>"+tdata[0].tablenamedisplay+"<h1>",                                            
    printFooter:"<h2><h2>",                                         
    autoResize:true,                                        
    pagination:"local",                                     
    paginationAddRow:"page",                                         
    paginationSize:20,                                      
    paginationSizeSelector:[25,40,50,100],                                       
    movableColumns:false,                                       
    tooltipsHeader:true,                                        
    columns:tdata[0],                                       
    data:tdata[1],                                  
    footerElement:myfooter,                                     
    rowClick:function(e, row){},                                     
    rowContext:function(e, row){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the browsers default context menu form 
    appearing.},
}];
      
//create table  
tabEquip[p] = new Tabulator("#"+vDDest, tabData[0] );
```

My table only prints the 20 rows that are visible due to pagination. I would like to print all rows.

Comment: I don't think it will work that way, Either don't use pagination or other option is to download the data in to a file.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Printing all rows only seems to work on a table that does not have pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as of Tabulator v4.8 in one of two ways.

Either by setting the ***printRowRange*** option to "active" in the table constructor, and then calling the print function:

```js
///define table
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    printRowRange:"active", //print all active rows
});

//print table
table.print();
```

Or by passing the string "active" into the ***print*** function when you call it:

```js
table.print("active", true);
```